# MQ Advanced Message Security error: AMQ9021E

Tags: ibm-mq

I have one queue encrypted with PRIVACY quality encryption. I configure the keystore and exchange certificates between the source and target and the target is able to write to the source's queue securely. The queue is on the source and is encrypted with the source's key. The target writes to the source with the sources public key.

When I try to add a second target writer, i perform the same steps.. Exchanging the source and target public keys across both nodes. when the new target attempts to write to the queue it gets an AMQ9021E error. Which appears that the source fails to find the targets CN. However, I can see the CN in the same KDB used for the first target and I know that it can find this certificate because a NEW queue shared between source and target2 works without issue.

I tried using REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL) on the source so it would refresh it's cache and allow the new messages to be read by target 2. Still doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know what I might be missing?
From the logs:

```
AMQ9021E: An error occured during the certificate import for the following DN:
CN=3a04d052-1e48-430b-8e2c-de8da6644ea0,O=IBM,C=US, result: 57
EXPLANATION:
The distinguished name is not present in the keystore or invalid. 
ACTION:
Consult the GSKit appendix in the Information Center for the explanation
of the GSKit reason code and take corrective action. If the problem persists, 
contact your IBM service representative.

AMQ9017E: IBM MQ security policy internal error: message could not be unprotected: GSKit
error code 851968, reason 62.
EXPLANATION:
The IBM MQ security policy interceptor could not verify or decrypt a message
because the indicated GSKit error occurred. This can happen for several
reasons, all of which are internal failures: (1) the message is not a valid
PKCS#7 message; (2) the sender's certificate does not have the required key
usage bit to be able to encrypt the message; (3) the sender's certificate was
not recognized as a trusted certificate; (4) receiver is not among the
recipients of the message
ACTION:
Consult the GSKit information in the Information Center for the explanation of
the GSKit reason code and take corrective action. If the problem persists,
contact your IBM service representative.
```

```
policy Definition

[dsadm@kobe1 - Db2wh /]$ /opt/mqm/bin/dspmqspl -m IJPYQVAD_CQM
Policy Details:
Policy name: IJPYQVAD_ADMINQ
Quality of protection: PRIVACY
Signature algorithm: SHA256
Encryption algorithm: AES256
Signer DNs: -
Recipient DNs:
  CN=996804c4-2fa6-4625-a4fd-acb8ab698b7f,O=IBM,C=US
Key reuse count: 0
Toleration: 0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: Can you add the whole of the error message you saw, rather than just the number. There are interesting inserts that form part of the message. Also can you show your policy definitions (both the working one for the new queue and the failing one) and the details from the certificate in question, i.e. DNs.

Comment: AMQ9021E: An error occured during the certificate import for the following DN:
CN=3a04d052-1e48-430b-8e2c-de8da6644ea0,O=IBM,C=US, result: 57

EXPLANATION:
The distinguished name is not present in the keystore or invalid.
ACTION:
Consult the GSKit appendix in the Information Center for the explanation of the
GSKit reason code and take corrective action. If the problem persists, contact
your IBM service representative.
AMQ9017E: IBM MQ security policy internal error: message could not be
unprotected: GSKit error code 851968, reason 62.

Comment: EXPLANATION:
The IBM MQ security policy interceptor could not verify or decrypt a message
because the indicated GSKit error occurred. This can happen for several
reasons, all of which are internal failures: (1) the message is not a valid
PKCS#7 message; (2) the sender's certificate does not have the required key
usage bit to be able to encrypt the message; (3) the sender's certificate was
not recognized as a trusted certificate; (4) receiver is not among the
recipients of the message.

Comment: @JacobdeVos update the question (click Edit button) to post new information rather than post it in the comments.

Comment: @JacobdeVos - AND... Also can you show your policy definitions (both the working one for the new queue and the failing one) and the details from the certificate in question, i.e. DNs